# How to run parser background mode?

Tags: parsing, joomla

I have:
1. Joomla Store
2. Parser Script written in PHP

Parser takes so much time. In admin I need to create button to run parser in background: Push Button -> Start process / so that you can close the browser but script should go on. Next time I push button - i can see a page with indicator, say the process has already started, wait.

I hope you understand my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as described.

You cannot start a process by clicking a button and push it in background, unless by using an advanced system with queue management and task runners.

The simpler solution that I can think of is:

- when you click the button, you create an empty file somewhere (i.e. a "semaphore" file)
- with cron or a similer scheduler, you check periodically that this file is present, and if it is, you delete the file and start the parser

Of course this assumes you have command line access to the server.